# Why does my right monitor get treated as the left monitor, and how do I fix it?

Tags: linux, nvidia, multi-monitor, zorin

I am running Zorin OS.
These are the methods I have tried:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --primary --output HDMI-0 --auto --left-of HDMI-1
```

This works, but doesn't apply after reboot. I can turn this into a .sh script and automatically run it at startup, I think, but I don't figure that should be necessary. EDIT: I tried to do this, but it doesn't work. I can run the .sh manually and it fixes it, but it doesn't work automatically on startup.

Another method I have tried is to configure my xorg.conf file. I put a file named "10-monitors.conf" in "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/" after following a tutorial. It does everything apart from making my right monitor behave like a monitor to the right (if I want to access the screen to the left I have to move my mouse to the right side of my primary screen). This is the contents of the "10-monitors.conf" file:

```
Section "Monitor"
   Identifier    "HDMI-0" 
   Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
   Option        "TargetRefresh" "60"
   Option "LeftOf" "HDMI-1"    
   Option        "Position" "0 0"

EndSection 

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier    "HDMI-1" 
   Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
   Option        "TargetRefresh" "60"
   Option "RightOf" "HDMI-0"    
   Option        "Position" "1920 0"
   Option "Primary" "true"

EndSection
```

Additionally, I have tried to tweak the values in "Position", and also change "LeftOf" and "RightOf", but that didn't do anything. So what I am thinking is that, either I have done it incorrectly, or something is changing the position values right after the "10-Monitors.conf" file has set the values, or overwriting it; but I do not know where to start to look for files that are possibly overwriting these values.

I have also tried to change the settings in NVIDIA x server settings, but that doesn't apply on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was very simple. Instead of changing display settings via nvidia-settings, I did it through my system settings. So settings -> Displays. Don't know how I did not think of this...